# internet explorer 10 Enable add-on

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-addons, internet-explorer-10

When I launch my IE10 browser, I very much want to enable the add-on. I keep getting this prompt. I keep hitting the enable button but dialog box stays there and nothing changes. How do I enable this add-on. I do have full sys admin rights on my machine.

[image]

In manage add-on window, I try to manually add it but Enable/Disable buttons are greyed out.

[image]

How do I enable this add-on?

Please help.

Comment: [See question by MXCHEN](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/86771-internet-explorer-add-ons-enable-disable-add-manager.html)